# Use instancing extension in twgl.js

Tags: webgl, twgl.js

I'm newbie in twgl.js. I want to know how to use extensions, especially instancing 
does it makes a simple way for us or I must use pure webgl inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instancing was added in v3.6.0.

To use instancing in twgl call set a `divisor` on your `FullArraySpec`s or `AttribInfo`s   If you created the WebGL context yourself call `twgl.addExtensionsOnContext`

It's suggested you use vertex array objects as twgl doesn't automatically reset the divisor for attributes where a divisor was previously set.

Example:

```js
const vs = `
uniform mat4 u_viewProjection;

attribute vec4 instanceColor;
attribute mat4 instanceWorld;
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_viewProjection * instanceWorld * position;
  v_color = instanceColor;
  v_normal = (instanceWorld * vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec4 v_color;

uniform vec3 u_lightDir;

void main() {
  vec3 a_normal = normalize(v_normal);
  float light = dot(u_lightDir, a_normal) * .5 + .5;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb * light, v_color.a);
}
`;


"use strict";
function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const v3 = twgl.v3;
  const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  twgl.addExtensionsToContext(gl);
  if (!gl.drawArraysInstanced || !gl.createVertexArray) {
    alert("need drawArraysInstanced and createVertexArray"); // eslint-disable-line
    return;
  }
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  function rand(min, max) {
    if (max === undefined) {
      max = min;
      min = 0;
    }
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
  }

  const numInstances = 100000;
  const instanceWorlds = new Float32Array(numInstances * 16);
  const instanceColors = [];
  const r = 100;
  for (let i = 0; i < numInstances; ++i) {
    const mat = new Float32Array(instanceWorlds.buffer, i * 16 * 4, 16);
    m4.translation([rand(-r, r), rand(-r, r), rand(-r, r)], mat);
    m4.rotateZ(mat, rand(0, Math.PI * 2), mat);
    m4.rotateX(mat, rand(0, Math.PI * 2), mat);
    instanceColors.push(rand(1), rand(1), rand(1));
  }
  const arrays = twgl.primitives.createCubeVertices();
  Object.assign(arrays, {
    instanceWorld: {
      numComponents: 16,
      data: instanceWorlds,
      divisor: 1,
    },
    instanceColor: {
      numComponents: 3,
      data: instanceColors,
      divisor: 1,
    },
  });
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);
  const vertexArrayInfo = twgl.createVertexArrayInfo(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

  const uniforms = {
    u_lightDir: v3.normalize([1, 8, -30]),
  };

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    const fov = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const zNear = 0.5;
    const zFar = 500;
    const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
    const radius = 25;
    const speed = time * .1;
    const eye = [
      Math.sin(speed) * radius, 
      Math.sin(speed * .7) * 10, 
      Math.cos(speed) * radius,
    ];
    const target = [0, 0, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];

    const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    const viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
    const world = m4.rotationY(time);

    uniforms.u_viewProjection = viewProjection;

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, vertexArrayInfo);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
    gl.drawElementsInstanced(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexArrayInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, numInstances);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```